# Interleave <li> elements from two <ul>s

Tags: jquery

I'm looking to join lists together using arrays so they go from the following:

```
<ul>
<li class="list-item">One</li>
<li class="list-item">Two</li>
<li class="list-item">Three</li>
</ul>

<ul>
<li class="container">Content One</li>
<li class="container">Content Two</li>
<li class="container">Content Three</li>
</ul>
```

To this

```
<ul>
<li class="list-item">One</li>
<li class="container">Content One</li>
<li class="list-item">Two</li>
<li class="container">Content Two</li>
<li class="list-item">Three</li>
<li class="container">Content Three</li>
</ul>
```

Below is what I've tried thus far but I'm kinda lost at this stage:

```
var nav = $(".nav-item");
var content = $(".container");

var array1 = jQuery.makeArray( nav );
var array2 = jQuery.makeArray( content );
$.each(array1, function(i, value){
    var str =  '<div class="nav-item">' + array1 + '</div>' + '<div class="container">' + array2 + '</div>';

    $(str).appendTo("body");
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: The "i" argument is the index.  Have you tried something like `array1[ i ]` and `array2[ i ]`, which look like they would contain `<li>...</li>` references?  I would suggest you create a variable `var li = [];` as an array. `li.push('<li class="list-item">'+array1[ i ].html()+'</li>'); li.push('<li class="container">'+array2[ i ].html()+'</li>');` within your `$.each...` and then afterwards use something like `$('body').append('<ul>'+li.join("\n")+'</ul>')` to append to the body.

Comment: You could remove the parent `<ul>` elements and then replace with the one in my previous comment, just as easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply use the `after` method:

```
var $list = $('ul:eq(1)').detach().children(); 
$('ul:eq(0) li').after(function(index) { 
   return $list.eq(index); 
});
```

[Here is a demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/27by5h8w/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this — http://jsfiddle.net/sergdenisov/mu47acb9/1/:

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="first-list">
    <li class="list-item">One</li>
    <li class="list-item">Two</li>
    <li class="list-item">Three</li>
</ul>

<ul class="second-list">
    <li class="container">Content One</li>
    <li class="container">Content Two</li>
    <li class="container">Content Three</li>
</ul>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var $listItems = $('.list-item');
var $containers = $('.container');
var $outerUl = $('<ul class="outer-list"></ul>');

var maxLength = Math.max($listItems.length, $containers.length);

for (var i = 0; i < maxLength; i++) {
    var $listItem = $listItems.eq(i);
    var $container = $containers.eq(i);

    if ($listItem) {
        $outerUl.append($listItem);
    }
    if ($container) {
        $outerUl.append($container);
    }
}

$('body').append($outerUl);
$('.first-list').remove();
$('.second-list').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this, assuming you want to retain the same order?

```
var list = $(".list-item");
var container = $(".container");

// Generate the list items, in your order
var mergedItems = Array();
list.each(function(i) {
    mergedItems.push(this); // list item

    var containerItem = container.get(i);
    if (typeof containerItem !== undefined) {
        mergedItems.push(containerItem);
    }
});

// Output
var list = $('<ul/>').appendTo('body');
$(mergedItems).each(function(i) {
    list.append(this);
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fx7azwzg/

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var listItems1 = [];
    $("#list1").children("li").each(function() {
        listItems1.push($(this).text())
    });


    var listItems2 = [];
    $("#list2").children("li").each(function() {
        listItems2.push($(this).text())
    });


    var list3 = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < listItems2.length; i++) {
        list3 = list3 + '<li>' + listItems1[i] + '</li>';
        list3 = list3 + '<li>' + listItems2[i] + '</li>';
    }
    console.log(list3);
    $("#list3").html(list3);

});
```

using the following HTML :

```
<body>
    <ul id="list1">
        <li class="list-item">One</li>
        <li class="list-item">Two</li>
        <li class="list-item">Three</li>
    </ul>
    <br>
    <br>
    <ul id="list2">
        <li class="container">Content One</li>
        <li class="container">Content Two</li>
        <li class="container">Content Three</li>
    </ul>
    <br>
    <br>
    <ul id="list3">
    </ul>
</body>
```

Assuming you want to keep the existing lists, the lists have the same number of list items.
http://jsfiddle.net/j942pk94/1/